# For loop is only storing the last value in colum

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull the week number given a date and then add that week number to the corresponding row in a pandas/python dataframe.

When I run a for loop it is only storing the last calculated value instead of recording each value.

I've tried .append but haven't been able to get anything to work.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

for i in df.index:
    
    week_number = date(df.year[i],df.month[i],df.day[i]).isocalendar()
    df['week'] = (week_number[1])

Expected values:

day month  year  week  
 8    12  2021    49  
19    12  2021    50  
26    12  2021    51  

Values I'm getting:
day month  year  week  
 8    12  2021    51  
19    12  2021    51  
26    12  2021    51
```

Comment: What do you think `df['week'] = (week_number[1])` is doing? Why do you think the output would be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Pandas `.apply` method to make it a one-liner:

```py
df["week"] = df.apply(lambda x: date(x.year, x.month, x.day).isocalendar()[1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it back at the correct corresponding, `i`, position. Using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), should help:

```
for i in df.index:
    week_number = date(df.year[i],df.month[i],df.day[i]).isocalendar()
    df.loc[i,'week'] = (week_number[1])
```

prints back:

```
print(df)

   day  month  year  week
0    8     12  2021    49
1   19     12  2021    50
2   26     12  2021    51
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, without using `apply` which is slow:

```
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['month'].astype(str) + '-' + df['day'].astype(str)).dt.isocalendar().week
```